# Dart repeating a function after it ends

Tags: dart

I have a long running function that does some background processing.

When the function completes I would like to repeat after a short delay.

What is the best way to do this?

I ended up with this messy code

```
  bool busy = false;
  new Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes:1) , (_)async {

    if( !busy){
      busy = true;
      await downloader.download();
      busy = false;
    }    
  });
```

Comment: Return a `Future`, wait for it to complete and then use `Timer` to delay the call.

Answer (score 3):

To repeat a function after a short delay after it's done, you:

- need to know when it's done,
- need to know when a short delay has passed,
- and needs to call the function again.

I'll create a separate function to do the calling and re-calling, because it gives a better separation of concerns.
For the first point, I'll assume the function returns a Future when it's done. Then there are lots of different ways to wait a short delay, I'll just use the most basic one, `new Timer`, and then repeat the process by calling the function again.

```dart
Future myFunction() {
  // do long operation in background, complete returned future when done.
}

void repeatMyFunction() {
  myFunction().then((_) {
    // using .then instead of .whenComplete, so we stop in
    // case of an error.
    new Timer(const Duration(millseconds: shortDelay), repeatMyFunction);
  });
}
```

If want to get the error back, you can create a new future:

```dart
Future repeatMyFunction() {
  Completer completer = new Completer();
  void loop() {
    myFunction().then((_) {
      // using .then instead of .whenComplete, so we stop in
      // case of an error.
      new Timer(const Duration(millseconds: shortDelay), loop);
    }, onError: completer.completeError);
  }
  loop();
  return completer.future;
}
```

If you allow multiple errors, and don't want to stop for one, you can return the errors as a stream, and, heck, add the function results as values just for good measure:

```dart
Stream repeatMyFunction() {
  StreamController controller = new StreamController();
  void loop() {
    myFunction().then(controller.add, onError: controller.addError)
                .whenComplete(() {
      new Timer(const Duration(millseconds: shortDelay), loop);
  }
  loop();
  return controller.stream;
}
```

None of these ways to repeat has a way to stop it again. For that, I'd pass an extra future to the repeat function and stop when that future completes.it

```dart
void repeatMyFunction(Future stop) {
  bool stopFlag = false;
  stop.whenComplete(() { stopFlag = true; });
  void loop() {
    myFunction().then((_) {
      if (!stopFlag) {
        new Timer(const Duration(millseconds: shortDelay), loop);
      }
    });
  }
  loop();
}
```

The other variants can also get a stop-future, and complete the future/close the stream when the stop-future completes.

Günter's suggestions are also fine, and much simpler (but with less fine-grained control, which is something I like to have). You can turn his code it into a stream using:

```dart
Stream repeatMyFunction() async* {
  while (true) {  // Stops if something throws.
    yield await myFunction(); 
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: shortDelay));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage/disadvantage using `Future.delayed` vs. `new Timer()` Isn't there a danger of running into a stack overflow as mentioned in my answer when `loop` calls itself even when it's async? I assume there isn't but I think I saw this mentioned recently in a bug report which made me unsure. If it's `async` the method returns immediately anyway.

Comment: There is a risk in creating a loop through (effectively) a tail-recursive call, whether async or not. If it's not async, you get a stack overflow. If it is async, you will last longer, but will eventually fill the heap with futures waiting for each other. With async/await syntax, it's an open question whether it can become a stack overflow anyway - that depends entirely on the implementation. To break the dependency chain, you have ensure that your futures don't  depend on each other linearly. The loop version does that - it deconstructs the futures created inside before creating a new one.

Comment: About `Future.delayed` and `new Timer` - I don't think there is any difference in practice. The problem comes when the function called by `Future.delayed` is recursive (asynchronously) because then each call creates a new `Future` which won't ever be completed. If you await a `Future.delayed` with no function at the end, then that future is completed and can be GCed - then you can loop in a non-Future based way and not accumulate uncompleted futures.

Answer (score 2):

```
Future myFunction() async {
  await downloader.download();
  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds:200),  myFunction);
}
```

or to avoid stack overflows which will happen when above code runs too long

```
Future myFunction() async {
  while(true) {
    await downloader.download();
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes:1), (){});
  }
}
```

Comment: But this will only run myFunction once.

Comment: Just add it at the end of your function and make it call itself with a delay. You need to wait for the returned future to complete before it starts itself again. I added `await` in my answer, you also need to mark your function with `async` to make this work.